Set maximum execution time for Express on Vercel
I deployed Express.js to vercel and It works relatively well.
I used this vercel.json:
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "index.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/"
    }
  ]
}

But my apis take long time sometimes. So I'd like to increase server execution time limit but I'm not sure how can I do it.
Now, I'm on Pro plan and I know I can set maximum execution time as 60s.
Thank you in advance.

I solved this issue by updating vercel.json like this:
{
  "version": 2,
  "functions": {
    "api/**/*.js": {
      "maxDuration": 60
    }
  },
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "destination": "/api"
    }
  ]
}

My entry point index.js file is in /api directory and other js files are in /src directory.
Originally, there were together in /api and my express app just returns source code of index.js.
After I move other js files to another directory, it worked fine.
